# "Visa" or "Other" in a UK visa questionnaire for EU Blue Card residents

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, residency, blue-card

I am a citizen of a European [non-EU country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus), living and working in and being a resident of an [EU country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poland). I want to obtain a [UK visit visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor) for tourism (primarily to visit certain places of interest in England and Scotland) and to spend some time with my friends (secondarily, also migrants from my home country who settled in London).

I do not have a national permanent residency permit or an [EU long-term residence permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_resident_(European_Union)) (**yet**, because I have not lived in a EU country for 5 years as required). Instead, being a highly-skilled, highly qualified worker, I have something called an [EU Blue Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Card_(European_Union)), a temporary resident card binding me to my current employer for 1 year (or 2 years, depending on how to interpret [certain conditions](https://www.apply.eu/directives/)).

While filling out a UK visa application, I found this question, and I have doubts about my answer:
[image: What permission do you have to be in Poland?]

I think I picked the right option, but I'm not 100 percent sure, because some may qualify a temporary residence card as a temporary visa (like, for example, a [UK student visa](https://www.gov.uk/student-visa)). What option, do you think, I should select?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't find anything to prove it, but I think the UK would consider the EU Blue Card a form of Visa, you definitely don't have permanent residence. However, I don't think they'll fail you for saying that the EU Blue Card is not what they think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've done it right. You're not a permanent resident, and the majority of the information I can find on the EU Blue Card indicates that it's not a visa per se, therefore you don't have a visa and you don't need a visa. You've put an explanation of your status and why you don't need a visa in the box where they tell you to do exactly that.

And remember, this is a human-reviewed process. If you have to make a mistake, it's better to make a weaker claim and offer useful context information (as you've done) than it is to claim you have a visa and then run into trouble later on. The person processing your paperwork should know what a blue card is. If a blue card is as good as a visa for their purposes then they can make a note on your application that says so.

Comment: Thank you, I _think_ your are right. I also wanted to ask what (do you think) I should add to the **Extra Information** text box but I just basically described myself, my character and my intentions being as transparent and straightforward as I possibly could have been. I will be applying in the next week, wish me luck :)

Comment: Just a small update: I've been issued a visa, so it looks like the option I picked was correct (disclaimer: it's not a legal advice)